# Blackberry Contact Listener

Tags: events, blackberry, listener, pim

i want to set event listener for the BlackBerry that changes some information to the contact when it change, add, edit contact. In my Application i want to get contact when use add new contact or edit contact.

Comment: Have you looked at the PIMListener class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple class that will listen to changes in the BlackBerry address book.

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.microedition.pim.Contact;
import javax.microedition.pim.ContactList;
import javax.microedition.pim.PIMItem;
import javax.microedition.pim.PIMList;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.pdap.PIMListListener2;


final class MyPIMListener implements PIMListListener2
{
    public void itemAdded ( PIMItem item )
    {
        if ( item == null )
        {
            return;
        }

        Contact contact = (Contact)item;
        // ...
    }

    public void itemRemoved ( PIMItem item )
    {
        if ( item == null )
        {
            return;
        }

        Contact contact = (Contact)item;
        // ...
    }

    public void itemUpdated ( PIMItem oldItem, PIMItem newItem )
    {
        if ( oldItem == null || newItem == null )
        {
            return;
        }

        itemRemoved(oldItem);
        itemAdded(newItem);
    }

    public void batchOperation ( PIMList list )
    {
        if ( list == null )
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            ContactList contactList = (ContactList)list;
            Enumeration e = contactList.items();

            while ( e.hasMoreElements() )
            {
                Contact contact = (Contact)e.nextElement();
                // ...
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

To use the above class, you need to add an instance of it as a listener to the BlackBerry contact list. Here is how you would do that:

```
MyPIMListener listener = new MyPIMListener();
ContactList contactList = (ContactList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(
    PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM_READ_ONLY);

BlackBerryPIMList blackberryContactList = (BlackBerryPIMList)contactList;
blackberryContactList.addListener(listener);
```